# Android studio C++ ndk camera

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-camera2

I created C/C++ project in android studio and I want to use NDK camera.
I wrote in my cpp file

```
#include <camera/NdkCameraMetadata.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraManager.h>
#include <camera/NdkCameraDevice.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_test_MainActivity_listDevices(JNIEnv* env, jobject)
{
   std::string text;

   ACameraIdList *camList;
   ACameraManager *camManager;

   camManager = ACameraManager_create();

   camera_status_t result = ACameraManager_getCameraIdList(camManager, &camList);

   if (result == ACAMERA_OK)
   {
       text = "Error List devices";
   }
   else
   {
       text = "Device listed";
   }

   return env->NewStringUTF(text.c_str());;
}
```

but Android studio is writing

> "Can't resolve type ACameraIdList"

What I'm doing wrong? I just added this code into .cpp file, nothing else. Idid not changed any other files.

Comment: Which platform level are you targeting? The native camera API requires 24.

Comment: I installed API level 24 and API level 28. I have Samsung Galaxy A7 with Android 7.0. but why Android Studio can not resolve that types?

Comment: I don't mean which SDKs you have installed. I mean which native API level you're _building for_.

Comment: for API level 24.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the problem you describe when I try it. I do get "Can't resvolve" errors in the IDE if I set the `minSdkVersion` to something lower than 24 (since the native camera API requires level 24 or higher). And of course you need to link against libcamera2ndk, otherwise you'll get link errors.

Comment: Thank you. I set minSDK version to 24 and problem fixed. it was 15 by default.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to set the minSDK to 24 or higher.

The NdkCameraDevice.h header files detects the minSDK using the `__ANDROID_API__` identifier:

```
#if __ANDROID_API__ >= 24
      ...
typedef struct ACameraIdList {
    int numCameras;          ///< Number of camera device Ids
    const char** cameraIds;  ///< list of camera device Ids
} ACameraIdList;
      ...
#endif
```

This means that if the minSDK is below 24 the C preprocessor will omit the declaration of ACameraIdList and other related structures and functions.  This leads to the "Can't resolve type ACameraIdList" error.